# torch silero tts. В v4_ru двоится голос у Баи и Ксении

Tags: python, pytorch, silero

https://github.com/snakers4/silero-models
В v4_ru двоится(ну или типо робовойсит) голос у Баи и Ксении(другими не пользуюсь)
в v3_ru такой проблемы нет(там правда иногда были проблемы с произношением некоторых слов, "все" например произносилось как "всё" и не только, в 4й такого нет)

видеокарта 1060 6гб

Пробовал и с cuda и с cpu
код стандартный из примера

```
audio_paths = self.model.save_wav(ssml_text=blok,
                                              speaker=f"{self.speaker_number}",
                                              sample_rate=24000,
                                              audio_path=fr"{self.audio_path}\{self.raw_title}-{str(num + 1)}.wav")
```

(текст всё ровно подкидываю с "+" ударениями, у меня уже так процесс налажен, надеюсь с этим не связанно)
sample_rate - менять пробовал

Пример голоса есть в таком же вопросе на гитхабе(там что то никто не ответил)
https://github.com/snakers4/silero-models/issues/250